# ASP.NET Core MVC URL : magic that makes HomeController become /Home in .NET 7

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-7.0

I'm trying to understand the under the hood magic that seems to be happening with ASP.NET Core MVC.

I create a new controller `DefaultTomatoController`, using "New Scaffold Item: MVC Controller - Empty"

Code is simply:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace MyTestApp.Web.Controllers
{
    public class DefaultTomatoController : Controller
    {
        public string Index()
        {
            return "this is my index action method";
        }

        public string Welcome()
        {
            return "this is my Welcome action method";
        }
    }
}
```

I then launch the app from VS 2022 and I can navigate to `http://localhost:<port>/DefaultTomato`. Neato. It works. All the clapping

Now this is what confuses me: I can also add a controller simply named `DefaultTomato2.cs` and navigate to `/DefaultTomato2`. Or I could just rename/delete recreate the original `DefaultTomatoController` and recreate it as `DefaultTomato.cs`.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace MyTestApp.Web.Controllers
{
    public class DefaultTomato2 : Controller
    {
        public string Index()
        {
            return "this is defaulttomato2 Index action method";
        }

        public string Welcome()
        {
            return "this is defaulttomato2 Welcome action method";
        }
    }
}
```

My question is: how are `DefaultTomato` and `DefaultTomatoController` both resolving to `/DefaultTomato`? What's the magic under the hood that drops the "Controller" portion of `DefaultTomatoController`? I don't like magic. It's tricky.

Comment: As a side note, I understand that "Controller" is a keyword.  Would one assume that at compile time, "Controller" keywords are stripped out of the class and file name or something?  Which makes me think I shouldn't use the controller key word when creating controllers so I can ensure no conflicts would occur when reviewing Call Stacks for example or errors denoting class names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called ["Conventional routing"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-7.0#conventional-routing). Nothing gets stripped at compile time. In ASP.NET Core route paths to actions can be inferred based on the Controller class name and the method names inside the Controller. When you have "ExampleController" only the part before "Controller" is considered part of the route by the framework. You can also define routes explicitly using the `Route` attribute.

**Edit**:

Here is a code snippet from ASP.NET Core source code that checks the controller class name and removes the `"Controller"` suffix.

https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/a419b2204d7eda5637142d03d980ee87a48054fe/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/ApplicationModels/DefaultApplicationModelProvider.cs#L163

```cs
controllerModel.ControllerName =
    typeInfo.Name.EndsWith("Controller", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ?
        typeInfo.Name.Substring(0, typeInfo.Name.Length - "Controller".Length) :
        typeInfo.Name;
```

There is similar convention with action names and the `"Async"` suffix:

https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/a419b2204d7eda5637142d03d980ee87a48054fe/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/ApplicationModels/DefaultApplicationModelProvider.cs#L362

```cs
private string CanonicalizeActionName(string actionName)
{
    const string Suffix = "Async";

    if (_mvcOptions.SuppressAsyncSuffixInActionNames &&
        actionName.EndsWith(Suffix, StringComparison.Ordinal))
    {
        actionName = actionName.Substring(0, actionName.Length - Suffix.Length);
    }

    return actionName;
}
```

So if you have:

```
public class DefaultTomatoController : Controller
{
    public async Task<IActionResult> WelcomeAsync()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

The route will be `/DefaultTomato/Welcome` and **not** `/DefaultTomatoController/WelcomeAsync`

Comment: That doesn't make much sense.  By that description, the framework would add "controller" to guess at class references to a route for all routes added.  Where it would be more efficient to strip the word "Controller" to more quickly tie to a route created by name.

Comment: This is how ASP.NET/ASP.NET Core MVC works since it was created. I bet the developers who designed the framework have found an efficient way to do it.

Comment: Ok so the substring does strip the keyword based on the source code provided above.  Thank you!  That helps a lot!